# How do I perform an LU Decomposition without pivoting?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I know that `LUDecomposition` in Mathematica does a pivoted decomposition, finding an $LU$ such that $PA = LU$. However, I have a $4 \times 4$ matrix and I need to do a decomposition on it such that $LU$ equals $A$, not some permutation of the rows of $A$. Is there some way in Mathematica for me to do a non-pivoted decomposition?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 4} 10];
{B, p, c} = LUDecomposition[A];
L = (LowerTriangularize[B, -1] + IdentityMatrix[Length[B], WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision])[[
   InversePermutation[p]]];
U = UpperTriangularize[B];
Max[Abs[L.U - A]]
```

> 8.88178*10^-16

It does the LU-decomposition with pivoting and reorders the matrix `L` accodingly. Of course, `L` is not necessarily lower triangular anymore. So this is maybe not what you are looking for...

Comment: Yeah, this works but I need the matrices to be triangular. Is that possible?